# How do the compiler and JVM establish and recognize a RuntimeException as a starting point as unchecked type?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, jvm, runtime

In Java, according with the following class hierarchy

```
Object
 Throwable
  Error
   Abort
   ...
  Exception
   AbortException
   ...
   RuntimeException
    ...
```

I know the concept and difference between a *checked* and *unchecked* terms, where the former is all the subclasses from `Exception` and the latter for all the subclasses from `RuntimeException`. Of course, and the constraints about `try/catch` and `throws` syntaxes.

Now because `RuntimeException` is a *subclass* of `Exception` **too**.

**Question**

- How do the compiler and JVM establish and recognize a `RuntimeException` as a starting point as unchecked type?

Or in other words:

- How both establish/recognize that the `RuntimeException` hierarchy must be *not* treat it as checked?

How **Java** itself implement this *specification* through its own code?

Comment: It's part of the spec and as such hardcoded into all compilers. Note that there is nothing special to do at runtime. Checked exceptions are a compiler-level feature only.

Comment: The JVM doesn't. (Un)checked is purely a Java language concept enforced by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The word, "checked" in the term "checked exception" refers to the exceptions that are checked during compilation time. JVM does not know anything about a checked exception. It's analogous to generics which is there to assist you in catching potential problems during compilation itself; the Type Erasure replaces all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods. So, JVM does not know anything about generics.

By the way, the checked exception classes are all subclasses of `Throwable` other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.